# How to setup Http proxy on Rhino

Tags: rhino, http-proxy

How to setup Http proxy on Rhino?

I tried following ways so far:

```
przemek@macbook:~/Downloads/rhino1.7.7.1/lib$ java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.10.1.69 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3210 -jar rhino-1.7.7.1.jar
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Rhino 1.7.7.1 2016 02 03
js> var url = new java.net.URL("https://somegate.pl/sms");
js> var urlConnection = url.openConnection();
js> urlConnection.usingProxy()
false
js> var proxy = new java.net.Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new java.net.InetSocketAddress("10.10.1.69", 3210));
js> var proxyUrlCon = url.openConnection(proxy);
js> proxyUrlCon.usingProxy()
false
```

but as you see, doesnt work.
Any ideas you could share with me?